# Using OAuthWebSecurity for external login and SqlMembershipProvider for internal login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-oauth, sqlmembershipprovider

In my MVC4 project I have defined connection string to database and have defined it as SqlMembershipProvider, it works fine for local account (Login and register). but in external (facebook) login and in ExternalLoginCallback method I got this error :

> "To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider"."

Here is membership node in web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I got the error here in ExternalLoginCallback method:

```
if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

while the result containing all the required information I wanted.

I found some answers on the net such as using WebMatrix.WebData and simpleMembershipProvider, but I do not want to use simpleMembershipProvider.

Any help will be appreciated :)